# MUI Select component, display different value than the selected value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of menu items inside a  [MUI Select component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/). Each menu item in the list displays an icon and text. When selecting a menu item, as expected the selected menu item is displayed as the selected value in the Select component. The selected value displays the icon and the text. Is it possible to have it only display the text without the icon even though it's part of the selected menu item? Is it possible to modify the text as well?

```
<Select value={selectedIndex} onChange={(e: any) => { //handleSelection })>
    <MenuItem value={index1}>
       <CoolIcon /> ItemText1
     </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={index2}>
       <CoolIcon /> ItemText2
     </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Select Component's](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) `renderValue` function allows you to have a custom selected value based on your choices.

```
<Select 
  value={selectedIndex} 
  onChange={(e: any) => { //handleSelection })
  renderValue={(selected) => {
   // here you can add you logic for your selected value
   return menuItems.find((x) => x.value === selected).label; // something similar to this
  }}
>
    <MenuItem value={index1}>
       <CoolIcon /> ItemText1
     </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={index2}>
       <CoolIcon /> ItemText2
     </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks renderValue is works